# Why would you not allocate all available memory to the heap?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, heap-memory

I am developing a small hobby OS as a learning experience and trying to wrap my head around kernel memory management. I am currently trying to wrap my head around memory allocation via a heap mechanism.

**What I am not clear on is the following:**

In several implementations I have reviewed, there is code to expand and contract the heap. But why would you not always use all available memory for the heap(s). What else is there (besides a small region for kernel code) that requires memory?

Comment: Generally, kernels have both a page memory pool and a non-paged pool. The side of the non-paged pool is usually configurable.

Comment: @user3344003 ok, but is the non-paged pool ever free'd then?

Comment: Not that I have seen.

Comment: `What else is there (besides a small region for kernel code) that requires memory?` - other processes ?